# How to join two tables from two columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have two tables

```
**Location**
id int 
name varchar
```

and

```
**User**
id int
name varchar
birthplace int
living_in int
```

where **birthplace** and **living_in** are references to the location **id**

I would like to display the output as

```
    Name Birthplace Living in
    Joe  LA         NY
    Bill Sac        Orl
```

My query

```
    select a.name, h.name as Birthplace, h.name as Living In
    from User a
    left join location h
    on a.birthplace= h.id
    left join location h
    on a.living_in = h.id
```

does not give the required result. Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Add the sample table data as well, for the expected result.

Comment: You need to have different aliases for your location tables - e.g. h1 and h2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With proper table aliases, it becomes much easier:

```
select u.name, b.name as Birthplace, l.name as LivingIn
from User u
left join location b
    on u.birthplace= b.id
left join location l
    on u.living_in = l.id
```